# How to open a source file in GDB

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb

I use GDB to attach to a running process and catch a breakpoint. I execute the following commands sequence:

> $ gdb -tui
>
> (gdb) attach PID

And now I have the GUI [TUI view](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/TUI.html) open without any source file in.

I have been desperately trying to google a way to load / open a source file to be able to execute command "break ", but unfortunately I could not find anything that would simply work.

Comment: How did you compile the program running in the process? Did you use `-g`? Did you issue `dir` commands to `gdb` ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yes, I compile it with "-g", but I do not think this have anything to do with my question, as I can successfully debug the app from start, when main.cpp is loading "automatically". Then I can set breakpoints, step into the code through other files etc. My problem is how to open a source file if it is not opened.

Comment: Can you show us either an image of your TUI window or the output of `bt`? When you attach to a process, it's likely that the current function is a system call interface, part of the C library, which in most Linux distros doesn't come with source code by default. All you need to do is go `up` a frame or two until you get to your own code.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem; it's amazing that such a basic function is so obscure.  My workaround is to use the file name and function name to set the breakpoint:

```
b <filename>:<function name>
```

Comment: Very frustrating and uncommonly tricky. I too want to do this but "b src/file.c:func" doesn't work for me.

Comment: @RichieHH did you try the method (above) that uses Alt-O?

Answer (score 2):

I FINALLY found out how to do this in cgdb:

1. Press Esc to go to the code window.
2. Press Alt-O.
3. Scroll down to the source file you want to open and press Enter.

Now you can set breakpoints in this file.

Answer (score 1):

I found that in gdb, the `list` knows about symbols, so

`l main()`

will open the main in whatever file it's defined (I'm assuming C in this example - you didn't specify a language).

`TAB` also completes function names (as on linux command line),

Answer (score 0):

Read the [examine source file](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Source.html#Source) chapter of GDB documentation.

You could use the `list` command.

Of course you need to set appropriately the directory list. Use the `dir` [command](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html).

The [GDB documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/index.html) starts with a tutorial chapter, so please read it.

Of course, all your software should be compiled with `-g` (or even  `-g3`) to get its debug information from the compiler.

BTW your source file is already opened by (that is : visible to) `gdb`. You could want to `list` part of it, or to put a breakpoint (using `break` or `tbreak`) in it. No specific action from your part is needed to have it visible to `gdb` (except perhaps the `dir` command).

Comment: The "answer" doesn't answer the user's question.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `list file.c:1` to show file.c content from line 1.